# Uso nell'italiano del termine "accortenza" in luogo di "accortezza"

Tags: word-choice, regional

Ho solo di recente scoperto che il termine *accortenza* è di utilizzo prettamente partenopeo, mentre la corretta forma italiana sarebbe *accortezza*.
Sembra che esso sia un regionalismo, considerato scorretto altrove, ma che ha uso tipicamente comune, informale ma anche formale, in quella zona del paese.

La cosa mi ha piuttosto sorpreso e son andata a cercare la ragione di questa discrepanza: [l'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/po-accortenza) chiarisce che i due sostantivi si son formati da due diversi suffissi latini e che *accortezza* è quello regolare, formatosi cioè da un participio passato usato come aggettivo. L'altra proviene morfologicamente da un participio presente.

Dal canto suo però *accortenza*, spulciando fonti storiche, pare abbia avuto una generica origine popolare, non relegata a Napoli, e sia stata in seguito acquisita stabilmente nell'italiano regionale della zona.

Si riporta anche una lieve differenziazione semantica: mentre *accortezza* è sinonimo di prudenza e accuratezza, *accortenza* ha il ruolo più generico di *attenzione*.

Mi chiedo se il termine (che, ripeto, per me è neuronalmente la forma giusta e mi tocca forzatamente sostituirlo con "accortezza") è in regioni diverse dalla Campania considerato del tutto scorretto, esclusivamente dialettale, se addirittura non verrebbe compreso.

Mi piacerebbe anche capire come si è storicamente sviluppato il confinamento ad una parte del paese di un termine di derivazione latina e di uso genericamente popoolare.

Comment: Non ti sorprenderà sapere che, pur condividendo il tuo dolore (oh povero e incompreso uscire transitivo!), non avevo mai sentito "accortenza" prima d'ora. Ti consoli il fatto che è molto più facile da digerire di altri regionalismi, come "in parte a" per significare "a fianco di". (Non essendo campano però non rispondo).

Comment: martina, l'unica *accortenza* in questo caso è avere l'accortezza di non usare *accortenza* fuori dal contesto regionale dove è usata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando guardiamo alla provenienza e all'uso delle parole in italiano, non dobbiamo dimenticare la storia della nostra lingua e della nostra penisola.

Malgrado oggi la nostra lingua sia comprensibile a tutti dalle Alpi alla punta della Sicilia, in passato non era così, e se anche gli autori che studiamo a scuola sembrano parlare tutti la stessa lingua quando smettevano di scrivere dovevano utilizzare il volgare/dialetto per parlare con chi li circondava. E ovviamente la distinzione italiano-dialetto non è dicotomica, ma ci sono mille sfumature tra l'italiano della crusca e il dialetto basso,

L'italiano soprattutto quello parlato, ma anche lo scritto, è sempre in bilico tra la lingua che si impara a scuola e la lingua che ci circonda. (Perfino chi non parla o capisce nessun dialetto, ahimè, è comunque immerso in un mondo che utilizza parole, costruzioni o prestiti da una lingua più "bassa").

Se a questo aggiungi che perfino in tempi recenti le occasioni di scambio tra parlanti di diverse regioni erano limitate alla carta stampata, libri e giornali, è facile immaginare che alcune parole o espressioni si siano costruite e conservate a livello locale.

Anche la suddivisione della penisola in diversi stati fino a 150 anni fa è un altra delle ragioni di questa situazione. Il linguaggio ufficiale delle leggi, e anche i programmi scolastici, aiutano la diffusione di un lessico comune. In tal senso puoi confrontare [l'italiano parlato in Italia con quello parlato in Canton Ticino](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/varie/varie_007.html), malgrado la vicinanza noterai sicuramente molte parole "sbagliate".

Queste sono alcune delle macroragioni dietro lo sviluppo di parole o espressioni locali; a queste poi se ne aggiungono di specifiche per le singole parole.